# How to check that ssh login was successful in a script?

Tags: ssh, login, php

I do run `ssh server "svn info /path/to/codebase"` from php. It works fine but I wan to know how to check if the ssh login was not successful.

I want to **check from my php script** that ssh server is up and **login process finished successfully**. How can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the return code from the `ssh` command.  If the command fails, `ssh` will return a non-zero exit code.  According to the PHP documentation, the [system](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) and [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) functions both allow you to capture the return code of a command in the *return_var* parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The return code is useful, but be aware that you can get a non-zero result if the ssh login succeeds but the remote command fails.  If you don't expect `svn info` to fail once you've logged in, then this is no big deal.

Comment: Good point so I can check both output of svn info and return code of ssh itself.